# Replace value in object

Tags: reactjs, object, foreach

I wish to replace some values in my data based on key, I have the below object:

```
const data = {
  data: {
    config: {
      bioObject: {
        dataBioOne: 1,
        dataBioTwo: "B",
        dataBioThree: "A",
        dataBioFour: 2,
        dataBioFive: 2,
        dataBioSix: 3,
        dataBioSeven: 1
      },
      pinObject: {
        dataPinOne: 5,
        dataPinTwo: "B0",
        dataPinThree: "A0",
        dataPinFour: 6
      },
      appletRegister: [
        {
          aid: "A",
          filterApplet: null,
          bioApplet: false,
          pinApplet: false,
          defaultApplet: true
        },
        {
            aid: "A",
            filterApplet: null,
            bioApplet: false,
            pinApplet: false,
            defaultApplet: true
          },
      ]
    },
    initialization: {
      defaultPin: "1111"
    }
  }
};
```

And I have two other objects contained in the above object - `bioObject` and `pinObject` properties. I wish to loop through the object and replace these two keys and their values with new elements.

My function looks like this:

```
 handleSChange = (bio, pin) => {
    let dataBio = bio;
    let dataPin = pin;
    let profile = this.state.data;
    console.log(Object.keys(profile.config));

    let obj;
    obj = Object.keys(profile.config).forEach((el) => {
      if (el == "bioObject") {
        el.replace(dataBio)
      }
      if (el == "pinObject") {
        el.replace(dataPin)
      }
    })
    console.log(obj);   
  }
```

But as far as I see I replace only keys, not it's values. If I change keys for values, then I cannot loop through key so won't be able to replace this particular data. Does anyone has any idea how to replace data in these two places?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to go about this. Below you will find one method. Another is using `Object.assign()` or ES6 object spread syntax. `...object`.

```js
const data = {
    config: {
      bioObject: {
        dataBioOne: 1,
        dataBioTwo: "B",
        dataBioThree: "A",
        dataBioFour: 2,
        dataBioFive: 2,
        dataBioSix: 3,
        dataBioSeven: 1
      },
      pinObject: {
        dataPinOne: 5,
        dataPinTwo: "B0",
        dataPinThree: "A0",
        dataPinFour: 6
      },
      appletRegister: [
        {
          aid: "A",
          filterApplet: null,
          bioApplet: false,
          pinApplet: false,
          defaultApplet: true
        },
        {
            aid: "A",
            filterApplet: null,
            bioApplet: false,
            pinApplet: false,
            defaultApplet: true
          },
      ]
    },
    initialization: {
      defaultPin: "1111"
    }
};

handleSChange = () => {
    let profile = data;

    let obj;
    obj = Object.keys(profile.config).forEach((el) => {
      if (el == "bioObject") {
        profile.config[el] = {
          /* Put the new properties here if you want overwrite the existing object */
          newProp: 'newProp'
        };
      }
      if (el == "pinObject") {
        profile.config[el] = {
          /* Put the new properties here if you want overwrite the existing object */
          newProp: 'newProp'
        };
      }
    })   
 }
 
 handleSChange();
 console.log(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since it appears you are using a React class component with state, the following should work:

```
this.setState({
    data: {
        config: {
            ...profile,
            bioObject: bio,
            pinObject: pin
        }
    }
});
```